# What is the Program Segment Prefix (PSP)?

Tags: assembly, dos

What exactly is Program Segment Prefix (PSP)?

I searched in Google but couldn't find any clean and straight answers to help me completely understand it.  What does it do and what is the use of it?

Comment: The PSP is a data structure used by DOS to describe processes.  Each process has one.  See [this article](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/371-psp__program_segment_prefix.html) and the article linked from it for details.  Not sure what you mean by “what languages supports it.”

Comment: I edited that part. It was a wrong question

Comment: Which of the questions remain open after reading the article I linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to run a program in DOS, its command processor `command.com` reserves a block from remaining free memory and fills a 256 bytes long structure called **PSP** in the beginning of this block. Image of the executable program is loaded from disk to memory right behind the PSP. Segment address of PSP is loaded into segment registers `DS` and `ES` and the program is launched.
If it is a COM program, `CS=DS=ES=SS` and instruction pointer `IP` is set right after the PSP, i.e. `IP=256`.
When the program is MZ executable, `CS:IP` and `SS:SP` are set from their corresponding fields in MZ header.

**Program Segment Prefix** is useful for the program in many ways:

- The launched program can inspect command-line arguments located at
  offset `80h` in PSP.
- Segment address of block of strings with environment
  variables can be found at `PSP:2Ch`.
- Program may hook and change
  the default system reaction to Ctrl-Break at `PSP:0Eh` or reaction to
  critical error at `PSP:12h`.
- At `PSP:16h` it can get PSP address
  of its parent process to find out whether it was launched from
  `command.com` or spawned from other executable program.
- And last
  but not least the return instruction `INT 20h` at `PSP:0` can be used
  in COM program to terminate itself by a single instruction `RET`.

More detailed description of PSP can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix).

Comment: "Program may hook and change the default system reaction to Ctrl-Break" -- The PSP fields are for restoring the parent's handlers during your termination. Anyway, in DOS v3+ the PSP is not created by the shell usually but by the `exec` system call, interrupt 21h service 4B00h or 4B01h.

Comment: What is a difference between the PSP and FCB?

Comment: @Bratw [File Control Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Control_Block) was used in early DOS versions to work with files. COMMAND.COM prepared one or two FCB from command-line arguments (I/O file names) and put them into PSP. This method is abandoned now in favour of DOS file functions.